# Zombie services: How do I remove services that turn up in event viewer but not under services

Tags: windows-xp, boot, services

I've had the same install of Windows XP since 2007, and its built up quite a bit of cruft over time. Its mostly not a problem, other than very slow post boot initialisation, and a whole load of errors related to services which belong to things I removed  - colinux driver and cdenable (from basalisk I think) - have been turning up on event viewer.

They do *not* however turn up in Windows services, msconfig or autoruns.

Where do I find these services?  And how do I disable or remove them?

one example would be

> The CoLinuxDriver service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: What kind of messages do you see in the event viewer ? can you provide an error message from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for them in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services
(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\CoLinuxDriver would be my guess)

You will not find it under the Services (services.msc) since it is a driver.

Try looking for them in [Sysinternals AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) under the "Drivers" tab

I suggest that you run [CCLeaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) it might be able to cleat this stuff out.

Comment: they were in the registry.